# jQuery: on change get the closest element for its text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to get the closest element to an input field so I can use the element's text/html as the value of the input field.

my jquery looks like this:

```
jQuery("[name=currencies]").val(Currency.currentCurrency).change(function() {
  $(".moneyPrice").val($("span.money").text());

});
```

the `span.money` and its text is being created dynamically.

the code above works in a way but it will put all the `span.money` in the input fields.

what I am trying to do is to get the closest `span.money` to each input fields and put its text in that input field.

I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/v6v146sv/

Please change the select options and take a note of the input fields values.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest` and `find` methods:

```
$(".moneyPrice").val(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.price').find('span.money').text();
});
```